# What are the different ways to have communication between an iOS app and a database server?

Tags: ios, xml, database, json, web-services

I just starting to play around with iOS and web services. I'm writing a test app (My Books Collection) where a user should be able to register, login and then add books (Name, Author, Price, Edition, etc) and all the data should be stored in a database server. What options do I have to achieve this functionality?

I have programming experience but I'm very new to iOS and web services. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to have a web application mediator. We use php to handle queries from ios app and manages db. We use a light weight xml for ios - php communication and also add encryption sometimes. You can also add data compression to keep data usage low.

Comment: So you mean, iOS talks to the web application and then web app takes care of processing the query and then iOS gets the result of the query over XML?

Comment: Yes, that's how we have been using for years now.

Comment: An alternative to lightweight XML is to use json which is very easy to learn and arguably quicker. [json vs xml](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2010/11/json-vs-xml.php) PHP is the normal handler for queries though.

Comment: How does the iOS app communicate with the web application? Using JSON?

Comment: You simply call the URL with parameters u need to send.

Comment: OK. So first step would be to have a web application ready to handle queries and then send requests to the URL with parameters and parse the data to display on iPhone. Correct?

Comment: Correct, We use simple string parsing for XML parsing. The XML architecture is kept very simple like only one straight info like <tag>data<\tag> <tag1>data1<\tag1> <tag2>data2<\tag2>